# How to set input field maxlength from label

Tags: javascript, ajax, limit, maxlength

I'm trying to figure out a way to change the maxlength of ajax called input fields by pulling the value to set out of the field's label and updating the default value. The field labels all follow the same format - id, class, type and maxlength. The new maxlength value to set is always present in the id ...max_X_characters...

```
`<input id="ecwid-productoption-16958710-Line_5_:0028max_4_characters:0029" class="gwt-
TextBox ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionTextField ecwid-productoption-
Line_5_:0028max_4_characters:0029" type="text" maxlength="200"></input>`
```

So in this example I need to set the maxlength to 4.

The other problem is that there are multiple input fields, often with different maxlength values. See [here](http://www.gewgawgiftstore.co.uk/#!/~/product/category=5561005&id=16958710) for an example.

I was thinking of setting a script to pull out the value once the fields have loaded, but I don't mind admitting it, this one's over my head - hopefully one of you bright guys n gals can figure it out!

**Update:** Thanks for the suggestions, I've tried both, in various combinations, but can't get them to work.

Here's the code suggested by Ecwid's tech team that sets all input fields on the page to one maxlength (6 in this case)

```
 `Ecwid.OnPageLoaded.add(function(page){if (page.type == "PRODUCT") {  
 $("input.ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionTextField").attr('maxlength','6');
 };
 })`
```

However, as I stated there are input fields with different maxlengths for some products.

I've tried replacing the '6' above with a function, based on your suggestions, to get the maxlength from the input id, but can't get it to work.

Any more ideas?

Thanks

**Update:**

Cracked it (nearly), here's the working code

```
`Ecwid.OnPageLoaded.add(function(page){
 var regex = new RegExp("max_(\\d+)_characters");
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
 var inp = inputs[i];
 if (regex.test(inp.id)) {
    var newLimit = inp.id.match(regex)[1];
    inp.maxLength = newLimit;
 }        
 }
 });`
```

Thanks so much for your help, it works like a dream on the product page but there is another area where it doesn't. A customer can edit the input text via a pop-up, from the shopping basket.

The fields have similar code:

```
`<input id="ecwid-productoption-16958710-Line_5_:0028max_4_characters:0029"
class="gwt-TextBox ecwid-productBrowser-details-optionTextField ecwid-productoption-
Line_5_:0028max_4_characters:0029" type="text" maxlength="200"></input>`
```

Suggestions very welcome

Chris

**UPDATE:**

Many, many, many thanks to ExpertSystem (you genius you!) - I think we've got it. (tested on IE10, firefox 21, chrome 27).

The code below is for people using Yola and Ecwid together, but I guess the original code may work for people using other sitebuilders. It limits the number of characters a user can enter into input fields, in Ecwid, by checking for a number in the input field's title (in this case the value between 'max' and 'characters') and replacing that as the field's maxLength value. It limits fields in the product browser, in the html widgets and in the cart pop-up.

Here it is:

Go to Yola's Custom Site Tracking Code section. In the 'Footer Code' column (actually placed at the bottom of the 'body'), place this code:

```
<script>
Ecwid.OnPageLoaded.add(function(page){
var regex = new RegExp("max_(\\d+)_characters");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var inp = inputs[i];
    if (regex.test(inp.id)) {
        var newLimit = inp.id.match(regex)[1];
        inp.maxLength = newLimit;
}        
}
});
</script>

<script>
var regex = new RegExp("max_(\\d+)_characters");
function fixMaxLength(container) {
    var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var inp = inputs[i];
        if (regex.test(inp.id)) {
            var newLimit = inp.id.match(regex)[1];
            inp.maxLength = newLimit;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

and this into the 'Header Code' column:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popupContent");
    for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        fixMaxLength(popups[i]);
    }
});
</script>
```

That's it! You're good to go.

Comment: If you use more characters in the ID and className fields, it will set itself out of agony! Good thing you at least properly closed the input!

Comment: If you can dynamically insert value X into the id/class name, why can't you just insert that value into the maxlength property in the source?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned, I'm using ecwid, so don't have any control over the maxlength source (I've tried asking them to add a maxlength selection box in the back end, but it's a no go). I can use javascript API to get or change some elements.

Comment: If that markup comes from a CMS or something similar, I would consider using something else, as that is not even close to valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what is meant by "ajax called input fields", but supposing that the input fields are created and added to DOM inside a success callback for some AJAX call, you can place the following piece of code in your pages `<head>`:

```
var regex = new RegExp("max_(\\d+)_characters");
function fixMaxLength(container) {
    var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var inp = inputs[i];
        if (regex.test(inp.id)) {
            var newLimit = inp.id.match(regex)[1];
            inp.maxLength = newLimit;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, at the end of the AJAX call's "onSuccess" callback, append this:

```
fixMaxLength(document);
```

**UPDATE**:
Based on your comments below, if you need to apply `fixMaxLength()` to div's of class "popupContent", which get dynamically added to your DOM, an easy way (not the most efficient though) would be adding a listener for DOM modification events (e.g. somewhere in `<head>`):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("popupContent");
    for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
        fixMaxLength(popups[i]);
    }
});
```

(NOTE: I have only tested it on latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, so I am not really sure for which other/older browsers this does work.)
(NOTE2: GGGS, has tested it (and found it working) on IE10 as well.)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help - now have another question.

Comment: Always glad to help :) If you have another question, make a new post here in SO. I bet lot's of people will be glad to help again.

Comment: I don't see the difference. The same function can be used. You probably need to place it somewhere else as well (besides `Ecwid.OnPageLoaded.add(function(page){...`) - maybe at the code that generates the HTML for the popup you mention.

Comment: Put your code plus the "ecwid" version into the site's footer and it has solved two out of three issues for me. Thank you again for your help, it's much appreciated

Comment: Soo...there's a third issue ! Bring 'em on ! :D

Comment: OK, I've figured out why the pop-up isn't changed by the code, it's loaded after the rest of the page and after the site footer where the code sits - it is actually the very last thing before the closing body and html. So I'm thinking I need the code to check for changes to the page - what do you think?

Comment: It is still not 100% clear how your DOM is created, but maybe you could use `document.onload` to wait for all DOM elements to be ready before calling the code for setting max-length.

Comment: Have a look at [link]http://www.gewgawgiftstore.co.uk. I'm using Yola for the main site, where the change maxlength code is in the site's global footer code section. Then I'm using Ecwid, AJAX driven ecommerce, where the input boxes originate. Ecwid loads a product browser which is held in the main body of the page and all the browsing and shopping interactions occur in there. The shopping bag 'change' button activates the pop-up, outside the product browser and gets added to the bottom of the html - when checking with 'inspect element'

Comment: @GGGS: I updated my answer to (hopefully) address this issue. You can try it out and come with feedback :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, it's working (see update above). I wasn't sure where to put the fixmaxlength document, so haven't included it - doesn't seem to matter, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You are very welcome ! Always glad to help :) (It is interesting how you are so thrilled about this answer, but never upvoted it :D)

Comment: I'm only new here, it won't let me!

Comment: Ohh, I see ! Now it makes sense :) I didn't know/remember there was such a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

How about a regular expression on your id attribute?  Such as the following:

```
jQuery('input').each(function() {
    var idVal = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var regex = /max_(\d+)_characters/g;
    var result = regex.exec(idVal);
    var length = result[1];
});
```

This is a loop over all the inputs.  Once this is run, the length variable will have the proper length each go through, for your next step.